# Programa python: Tabla funcion seno

Tags: python

Realizar un programa que muestre por pantalla una tabla con los valores correspondientes al seno desde 0 grados hasta 9 veces un valor incremento (expresado en grados) que se ingresa por teclado. El valor del incremento ingresado deberá siempre considerarse entero.

He llegado a esto, pero no se como terminarlo, no se actualiza con los valores ingresados; si me pueden dar una mano se agradeceria.
Valores ingresados: 1, -1, 10, -10, etc. Arrojan todos el mismo resultado.

por ejemplo:

Tabla de senos de 0 a 90

Grados | seno

---

0     | 0.000000

10     | 0.173648

20     | 0.342020

30     | 0.500000

40     | 0.642788

50     | 0.766044

60     | 0.866025

70     | 0.939693

80     | 0.984808

90     | 1.000000

```
from math import sin,pi

incremento = int(raw_input("Incremento: "))
print
incremento*= 9

print ("Tabla de senos de 0 a %2.1d" %incremento)
print ("Grados | seno")
print ("-----------------")


incremento = 0
while incremento <= 9:
    print ("%2.1d %3.1s | %1.6f" %(incremento,"",sin(incremento * pi / 180)))
    incremento += 1
```

Comment: El código es una rara mezcla de Python 2.x y 3.x ¿Con cual trabajas en definitiva?

Comment: Pides el `incremento`, pero luego dices `incremento = 0`. ¿Cual es la lógica?

Comment: Es python 2.x, la verdad que soy nuevo en el tema. Lo interprete asi, y es lo que salio. Cuando lo ejecuto no se actualizan los valores de seno.

Comment: Claro que te tiene que dar el mismo resultado siempre, pues descartas el valor ingresado por el usuario y siempre iteras desde cero, en incrementos de un grado.

Comment: Alguna sugerencia??

Comment: @ChristianJonathanMedina Como dijo @CandidMoe Intenta declar una variable distina para el bucle: `while i<=9:    """"You codes"""";    i+=1;` o simpremente usa un bucle for: `for i in range(10):   
"""El mismo bucle incrementa i"""; `. Y ve como te sale.

Answer (score 0):

En tu código reasignas el valor incremento a cero luego de solicitarlo al usuario, ¿cuál es el objetivo de esto?

Supongo que al pedirle un dato al usuario lo que quieres hacer es algo con este valor, no entiendo del todo que quieres hacer, pero por ejemplo si tienes planeado hacer una operación matemática con el valor que te da el usuario iterando 9 veces, podrías:

```
cunter = 0
while counter <= 9:
    print ("%2.1d %3.1s | %1.6f" %(incremento,"",sin(incremento * pi / 180)))
    counter += 1
```

Y te recomendaría cambiar el nombre de la variable "incremento" por algo más claro, variable_de_usuario, math_var, etc... Esto hace el código más Pythonico.

```
variable_mat = int(raw_input("ingresa un número: "))
variable_mat *= 9
```